# graphical gui editor which incorporate database tables with python

Tags: python, user-interface, data-binding, datagrid

**(from your own experience)**

Is there a graphical UI editor / designer tool, commercial or free, which is able do design forms, and supports database-bound tables, before writing any line of code?

PyQt Designer can't work with Databases, AFAIK (do you know how?)

Dabo is the only thing so far that more or less works, but is quite heavy on resources, and not easy (for me) to work with, it doesn't support WebKit, and has an inconvenient code editor.

i'm interested in working with either QT or WX toolkits. Gtk is rules out due to dependecies and deployment issues on Windows.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried DBeaver?